# What's the effect of Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x92\\xA5Th...' for column 'text' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql

I am streaming tweets into MySQL database. I read lots of other questions and I know what have caused this warning but I don't understand the effect of this. Is it case 1: This whole single tweet wasn't successfully added to the database

or case 2: The recognizable part of this tweet is added to the database, only the part that is not recognizable is left out.

How can I make sure about this? Is there anything like a log that I can read?

Comment: I believe it is case 1. But this error can be easily fixed. Can you add your code as well? Generally this is a string formatting error when you `execute`.

Comment: It seems like I need to change my character set and character collation. I googled a lot, but still don't know how to change them. I want to change the default of them to utf8mb4, looks like I have to go to command line.

Comment: Can you please include your code as well?